# Error 'missing from-clause entry' in Query with 'union' and 'order by'

Tags: postgresql

I have a query with 3 unions and an order by clause.

So if s1, s2, s3 and s4 are string variables containing select queries and oc is a string variable containing an order by clause, the full query is :

```
s1 & " union " & s2 & " union " & s3 & " union " & s4 & oc
```

Each select is of the exact same format, just different arguments and each contains a number of joins.

This query fails with the error

> Run-time error : '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> missing from-clause entry for table "eventTbl";   Error while
>   executing the query

However, all the following variations do not cause an error

```
s1 & " union " & s2 & " union " & s3 & " union " & s4

s1 & oc

s2 & oc

s3 & oc

s4 & oc
```

The query causing the error works OK on the same database in .mdb format.

The postgresql server is postgres 9.0
The program is vb6 with ADO 2.6 and the connection string is

> Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={PostgreSQL
>   ANSI};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbname;UID=postgres;PWD=password;CONNSETTINGS=SET
>   Datestyle TO
>   'DMY'%3b;BOOLSASCHAR=0;TEXTASLONGVARCHAR=1;TrueIsMinus1=1;

EDIT
structure of each individual select is as follows:

```
 select Charges.CHARGESCALENAMEF1, MATERIALST12.MATERIALNAMEF1
   , workspecificationst11.*
   , clientdetail.clientidf9
   , eventTbl.*
 from Charges
 right join (MATERIALST12 
            right join  (workspecificationst11 
                         right join (clientdetail
                                      right join  eventTbl
                                      on clientdetail.clientidf9 = eventTbl.clientidf2
                                    ) on workspecificationst11.serialnumf5 = eventTbl.workf5
                         ) ON MATERIALST12.SERIALNUMF3 = eventTbl.MATERIALF8
           ) ON Charges.SERIALNUMF2 = eventTbl.CHARGESCALEF7
 where eventTbl.clientidf2 = 15249
 and  eventTbl.workf5 = 40
 and  eventTbl.workstatusf14 = 2
 and eventTbl.section = 1
 and workspecificationst11.showinaccountsf9 = true
  ;
```

Comment: What is `s1 &` ? Please post real code.

Comment: @wildplasser I've edited the question to show the make up of the selects

Comment: '&' is the string concatenation operator in vb6

Comment: There is no table "tablename" in your query, it must be some other query that fails.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Sorry I just fixed that now. Sorry I guess posted the question in a sort of an abstract way. Yes it's the table in the query eventbl that's missing the from clause though I can't see how

Comment: `right join (MATERIALST12 ` -->> `right join (SELECT ... FROM MATERIALST12` . (But you probably could remove al the parentheses) And the subquery needs an alias.

Comment: wow, surviving with VB6 in 2014 (and using postgres not MSSQL?)

Comment: @Davos make that 2017

Comment: For a language last released in 1998, that ceased being supported in... wait what? It's still supported! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vb6/vb6-support Yeah rock solid innings VB6. Now they should open source it.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the actual original order by clause, and post your solution as an answer and mark it the answer. Other answers here telling you to refactor the query are opinionated and don't address your actual issue. The queries themselves aren't that bad, apart from the fact most people never use right-joins. Constructing queries dynamically means predicate values are very selective, which is great, as long as you have the right indexes set up for seeking and joining. The legacy column names from Access is a shame but probably well established meaning in your org.

Comment: I was briefly responsible for a VB6 & Access '97 application many years ago that had a large amount of missing or corrupted data that I had to update. I couldn't find a copy of Access 97 anywhere and had to find a weird third party query tool and with a stack of paperwork reenter all the bad data. It brings back some nightmares! But looking back Access was the bad part, not VB6. In the 3 years since did you manage to get most of the "hairy old sql" running? Complete with nested right joins and other venerable oddities?

Comment: yes, there was little enough of the sql that needed touching thankfully cos there's a ton of the stuff. IIRC there were more incompatibiliies with sql for access with sqlserver than with postgresql. Shared access database was not a problem until people started using wifi networking then it was a nightmare!

Comment: @Davos this was all so long ago that I'd say you are more familiar with it at this stage than I am. If you want to put up a solution to this type of issue then I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the full query would end up looking something like the following, although I've simplified it to just two `SELECT` statements with a `UNION` between them, and finally an `ORDER BY` clause. Based on your comments above, you discovered that:

**A `table alias`(in your case `eventTbl` ) in an *`ORDER BY` clause doesn't work when the query contains `UNION`*.**

I suspect this is because each of the select queries has a local table alias for `eventTbl` , but collectively the query doesn't have a table alias at the scope of the entire query. Also, the `ORDER BY` is applies to the entire result set, not to the individual `SELECT` statements.

```
SELECT Charges.CHARGESCALENAMEF1, MATERIALST12.MATERIALNAMEF1
   , workspecificationst11.*
   , clientdetail.clientidf9
   , eventTbl.*
 from Charges
 right join (MATERIALST12 
            right join  (workspecificationst11 
                         right join (clientdetail
                                      right join  eventTbl
                                      on clientdetail.clientidf9 = eventTbl.clientidf2
                                    ) on workspecificationst11.serialnumf5 = eventTbl.workf5
                         ) ON MATERIALST12.SERIALNUMF3 = eventTbl.MATERIALF8
           ) ON Charges.SERIALNUMF2 = eventTbl.CHARGESCALEF7
 where eventTbl.clientidf2 = 15249
 and  eventTbl.workf5 = 40
 and  eventTbl.workstatusf14 = 2
 and eventTbl.section = 1
 and workspecificationst11.showinaccountsf9 = true

UNION

SELECT Charges.CHARGESCALENAMEF1, MATERIALST12.MATERIALNAMEF1
   , workspecificationst11.*
   , clientdetail.clientidf9
   , eventTbl.*
 from Charges
 right join (MATERIALST12 
            right join  (workspecificationst11 
                         right join (clientdetail
                                      right join  eventTbl
                                      on clientdetail.clientidf9 = eventTbl.clientidf2
                                    ) on workspecificationst11.serialnumf5 = eventTbl.workf5
                         ) ON MATERIALST12.SERIALNUMF3 = eventTbl.MATERIALF8
           ) ON Charges.SERIALNUMF2 = eventTbl.CHARGESCALEF7
 where eventTbl.clientidf2 = 15249
 and  eventTbl.workf5 = 40
 and  eventTbl.workstatusf14 = 2
 and eventTbl.section = 1
 and workspecificationst11.showinaccountsf9 = true
ORDER BY eventbl.datef1, eventtbl.eventidf15;
```

Removing the table aliases from the `ORDER BY` works, because taken as a single query, the above returns a `datef1` column and an `eventiff15` column, but doesn't define a table alias across the entire result set.

**SOLUTION**
***Remove the table alias from the `ORDER BY` clause:***

```
ORDER BY datef1, eventidf15;
```

I suppose you could make the table alias work if you did something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
( Original full query goes here without the order by) AS eventTbl
ORDER BY eventbl.datef1, eventtbl.eventidf15;
```

But that's a bit excessive.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all the parentheses:

```
select Charges.CHARGESCALENAMEF1, MATERIALST12.MATERIALNAMEF1
   , workspecificationst11.*
   , clientdetail.clientidf9
   , eventTbl.*
 from Charges
 right join eventTbl ON Charges.SERIALNUMF2 = eventTbl.CHARGESCALEF7
 right join clientdetail on clientdetail.clientidf9 = eventTbl.clientidf2
 right join MATERIALST12 ON MATERIALST12.SERIALNUMF3 = eventTbl.MATERIALF8
 right join workspecificationst11 on workspecificationst11.serialnumf5 = eventTbl.workf5
 where eventTbl.clientidf2 = 15249
 and eventTbl.workf5 = 40
 and eventTbl.workstatusf14 = 2
 and eventTbl.section = 1
 and workspecificationst11.showinaccountsf9 = true
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately removing the parentheses didn't change the error, same one came up :( I am just getting my toes wet with postgresql so I will look up your other suggestions about using aliases etc. I guess I was hoping that we'd be able to more or less reuse our hairy old sql that worked for the db in mdb format if the database was moved to postgresql. It's a bit frustrating because the performance with other queries is great!

Comment: Before creating all the UNIONs, start by testing the separate components. (BTW: all these RIGHT JOINS look *very* strange ...)

Comment: It's the combination of at least 1 'union' of those 'select' queries with the 'order by' clause tacked onto the end that causes the problem. if I leave out the 'order by' the query works. Also if I have no union but just use 1 'select' with the 'order by', that works too. That's what's so puzzling.

Comment: "all these RIGHT JOINS look very strange ..." They are very old and venerable queries and thus are beyond caring about appearances anymore!

Comment: "They are very old and venerable queries ..." They are also syntactically wrong. Fix them first before guing them together.

Comment: Yes it certainly looks like that will be necessary!

Comment: I don't know if this is of any interest to anyone. The 'order by' clause was ' order by eventbl.datef1, eventtbl.eventidf15 '. Changing this to simply ' order by datef1, eventidf15 ' fixed the problem.

Comment: When you have UNIONS, the implicit names in the result set can get lost because there are now *4* "eventTbl" entries, not just one.  This affects the ORDER BY which must follow all of the UNION selects.  With a UNION, the column name is (generally) predictable for ORDER BY, the numeric position (e.g. 'order by 6 asc, 8 asc') is always workable.

Comment: @kjack thanks removing the alias from the order by magically solved this. I guess it makes sense when the order by applies across all parts of the `UNION` but the alias only applies to one part of it.

Comment: @Davos Thanks, glad it was of help somehow

Answer (score 1):

Suggest a refactor:

```
WITH parms as (
   SELECT 15249 as clntid, 40 as wrkf, 2 as wkstat, sect = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 14349 as clntid, 37 as wrkf, 23 as wkstat, sect = 5
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 16822 as clntid, 106 as wrkf, 55 as wkstat, sect = 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 24253 as clntid, 9 as wrkf, 43 as wkstat, sect = 9
)
from 
    CHARGES
       right join 
    eventTbl 
          ON Charges.SERIALNUMF2 = eventTbl.CHARGESCALEF7
       right join 
    clientdetail 
          on clientdetail.clientidf9 = eventTbl.clientidf2
       right join 
    MATERIALST12 
          ON MATERIALST12.SERIALNUMF3 = eventTbl.MATERIALF8
       right join 
    workspecificationst11 
          on workspecificationst11.serialnumf5 = eventTbl.workf5
       RIGHT JOIN 
    PARMS 
          ON (
              eventTbl.clientidf2 = PARMS.clntid
              and eventTbl.workf5 = PARMS.wrkf
              and eventTbl.workstatusf14 = PARMS.wkstat
              and eventTbl.section = PARMS.sect
          )
WHERE
   workspecificationst11.showinaccountsf9 = true
```

Comment: Thanks, only just seen this now. Yes the original query is terrrible

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was simply that I had misspelled the table name and, as the other answers pointed out, SQL was thinking that that was an alias for a table.